# How do i remove confliction with the libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a function that uses scrolling sliding effect when I click on a link it slides down and takes to that div but i also placed another library for sliding navigation bar when we click on menu it slides form right to left and navigation menu opens but the problem is that both are not working when both are active if i remove the slide menu library the page sliding effect is working fine but when I add slide menu library it stops how can I make both to run ??

```
//main.js which is using sliding page effect pparallax we say i beleive them
$(document).ready(function(){
// Add smooth scrolling to all links
 $("a").on('click', function(event) {

// Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
if (this.hash !== "") {
  // Prevent default anchor click behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Store hash
  var hash = this.hash;

  // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
  // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 800, function(){

    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
  });
} // End if
});
});
```

Here is my footer where I have placed the libraries

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/BootSideMenu.js"></script>//if this is removed everything is working fine   
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#navigation').BootSideMenu({side:"right"});
    });
</script>
```

Please can anyone help me out my english is a bit bad so sorry for incorrect tenses :)

Thank You

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:css]?

Comment: I highly recommend creating a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with a working example so that we can assist further.

Comment: Does it collide with your custom code or between 2 other libraries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid javascript namespace conflict?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666634/how-to-avoid-javascript-namespace-conflict)

Comment: I am unable to figure out what exactly is happening :(

Comment: You marked as duplicate and the code he provided is different as my code isn't it ??

Comment: @FrankerZ it's a big codes what codes should i post should I post the link of website ??

Comment: Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified. Help us, help you.

Comment: I stated in my question <script src="js/BootSideMenu.js"></script>//if this is removed everything is working fine

Comment: This is the code hich is not letting my page sliding jquery to work $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#navigation').BootSideMenu({side:"right"});
  });

Comment: http://wintroninformatics.com/